# Function single to 4 bytes array

Tags: matlab, simulink, ieee-754

I want to create a function in MATLAB which converts a string into a 4 bytes array.
I've found this function `typecast` which works perfectly,
but I want to store the four bytes into my four outputs.

```
tab = typecast(single(30),'uint8')
```

This gives `tab = 00 00 f0 41`. 
I try to display `tab(0)` but it shows the error

> Subscript indices must be real positive or logicals

Can anyone help me to create the function and how to call it to get my four bytes?
I want to include it in a Simulink block to do the conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indices in MATLAB start from 1, not 0. Try `tab(1)` instead.

Comment: thank you, i used to do that in java. now it works (y)